# How to make this Query without using UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I am not very good at making query's. So could someone explain and help me with this query?

I need to inner join 2 tables 'Slaap' And 'Eten'. i need all 'eten' where ID = 5 and i need all 'Slaap' where ID = 5. I could only achieve this with a UNION but that is what i dont want because this query is for making the latest activity so i can use ORDER BY but i can't because of the UNION.

This is my current Query:

```
SELECT e.tijd, e.product_1, e.product_2, e.product_3, s.van, s.tot, s.slaapoptie 
FROM users u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN eten e on e.user_id = u.id AND e.id = 5 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN slaap s on s.user_id = u.id WHERE u.id = 5 
UNION 
SELECT e.tijd, e.product_1, e.product_2, e.product_3, s.van, s.tot, s.slaapoptie 
FROM users u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN eten e on e.user_id = u.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN slaap s on s.user_id = u.id AND s.id = 5 
    WHERE u.id = 5
```

With as result

[image: query]

I want the same result but without using UNION so someone explain this for me and how can i achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM( SELECT e.created_eten, e.tijd, e.product_1, e.product_2, e.product_3, s.created_slaap, s.van, s.tot, s.slaapoptie FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN eten e on e.user_id = u.id AND e.id = ? LEFT OUTER JOIN slaap s on s.user_id = u.id WHERE u.id = ? UNION SELECT e.created_eten, e.tijd, e.product_1, e.product_2, e.product_3, s.created_slaap, s.van, s.tot, s.slaapoptie FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN eten e on e.user_id = u.id LEFT OUTER JOIN slaap s on s.user_id = u.id AND s.id = ? WHERE u.id = ?
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT e.tijd, e.product_1, e.product_2, e.product_3, s.van, s.tot, s.slaapoptie 
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     eten e 
     ON e.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     slaap s 
     ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 5 AND
      (e.id IS NOT NULL OR s.id IS NOT NULL);
```

Note that I replaced the `5` with `u.id`.  I am guessing that is the intention.

The final condition in the `WHERE` is just checking that at least one condition matches.

Comment: This returns me nothing, it is just empty

Comment: @TehGaz7 . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?

Comment: [DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/otRBd6V4wfy6yNKvWL3sQw/0) @Gordon

Comment: @TehGaz7 . . . I see, the additional condition is only on `slaap`, not `eten`.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

seems you want users that have at eten or slaap..
so you can do

```
SELECT e.tijd, e.product_1, e.product_2, e.product_3, s.van, s.tot, s.slaapoptie 
FROM users u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN eten e on e.user_id = u.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN slaap s on s.user_id = u.id 
WHERE u.id = 5
and (e.id = 5 or s.id = 5)
```

Comment: This returns everything x2 and not the same as i expected [link](https://i.imgur.com/EOvnXeZ.png)

Comment: @TehGaz7 edited my answer was cheking user_id instead of e.id  and s.id as you do in union

Comment: still the same. No results. Above is the DBFiddle

Comment: you see that  have no slaap or etan with id 5, right? it is espected?

to have the same return of your union all you would need a outer join, that is not available in mysql 5.7